# IndexError on slicing array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I assume I'm asking a newbie question but have spent too much time today searching for an answer. I get an `IndexError: too many indices for array` error when naively attempting to perform the same slice operation on a numpy array after saving and reloading with `np.genfromtxt`.

Note: I see that the dimension has changed from (3,6) to (3,) upon reloading but was unable to convert the result back to dimensions (3,6)- this is the part I assume must be obvious (or maybe I need to specify type differently)

```
yo = np.arange(18)
yo = yo.reshape(3,6)

print(yo)
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]]

print(yo[:,:2])
[[ 0  1]
 [ 6  7]
 [12 13]]

np.savetxt("test_data.csv", yo, delimiter=",",  fmt='%1.4e')
yo_reloaded = np.genfromtxt("test_data.csv", dtype=(float, float, float, float, float, float), delimiter = ",")

#same as above but doesn't work
print(yo_reloaded[:,:2])
IndexError: too many indices for array

print(yo_reloaded)
[(  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.) (  6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.)
 ( 12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.)]

# shape changed
print(yo_reloaded.shape)
(3,)
```

Comment: Omit the `dtype` for genfromtxt. float is the default. Giving multiple dtypes tells it to load it as a structured array.  Look at the dtype of the reload.

Comment: It works- thank you @hpaulj

Answer (score 1):

Use `dtype=None` to tell `genfromtxt` to attempt to intelligently guess the `dtype`. In this case, since all values are floats, `genfromtxt` will assign a floating-point dtype to the array:

```
In [19]: yo_reloaded = np.genfromtxt("test_data.csv", dtype=None, delimiter = ",")
In [21]: yo_reloaded.dtype
Out[21]: dtype('float64')
```

and `yo_reload` will have shape `(3,6)`.

In contrast, if you set `dtype=(float, float, float, float, float, float)`:

```
yo_reloaded = np.genfromtxt("test_data.csv", dtype=(float, float, float, float, float, float), delimiter = ",")
```

then `yo_reloaded.dtype` becomes:

```
In [18]: yo_reloaded.dtype
Out[18]: dtype([('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8')])
```

which is the dtype of a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). The shape of the structured array is `(3,)` become NumPy views this array as consisting of 3 rows with each row having a single value consisting of 6 fields of floating-point dtype. That's simply not what you want, but what you get when you set `dtype` to equal a tuple of types.

Note you could also obtain the desired array using `dtype=float`:

```
In [24]: yo_reloaded = np.genfromtxt("test_data.csv", dtype=float, delimiter = ",")
In [25]: yo_reloaded.shape
Out[25]: (3, 6)
In [26]: yo_reloaded.dtype
Out[26]: dtype('float64')
```

Or, as [hpaulj points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602197/indexerror-on-slicing-array/49602279?noredirect=1#comment86211728_49602197), you could simply omit the `dtype` parameter altogether, in which case it defaults to `dtype=float`.

Comment: Your name spelled backwards is ubtunu... o_o

Answer (score 1):

if you run `print(yo_reloaded.shape)` before `print(yo_reloaded[:,:2])` you can see that your `np.genfromtxt()` call returns `(3,)` which means 3 rows with one column data.

When you use `dtype=(float, float, float, float, float, float)` you are mapping every row in `"test_data.csv"` 5-tuple. So `np.genfromtxt()` returns every row as a 5-tuple element.

In order to get the same results you  have to change `dtype=dtype=(float, float, float, float, float, float)` to `dtype=float`.